# alert not running inside jQuery ready statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not an expert in jQuery and find myself scratching my head. It was suggested to me by the lead developer of a piece of software that I make a copy of a js file using jQuery and make some very minor changes to it. I didn't think this would work as it would conflict with their original. It didn't seem that my code was being run, so just for a test I decided to throw in an alerts inside the ready section and sure enough it didn't alert inside the ready section of the copy. Can anyone explain this? My copy gets called first.

original.js

```
alert("original js running");
var originalVar = {
runHeartbeat : false,
inAdmin : false,

ready : function () {
alert("original ready is running");
/**a ton of code that seems to run such as addent event handlers to DOM elements*/

}
```

copy.js

```
alert("copied js running");
var copiedVar = {
runHeartbeat : false,
inAdmin : false,

ready : function () {
alert("copy ready is running");
/**a ton of code*/
}
```

Both alerts for original.js are displayed, but only the "copied js running" is displayed from copy.js. From what I've read you can add multiple document.ready methods but this code is handling the ready method differently.

Comment: How are you using `copiedVar`?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple `document.ready`, thats not a problem. Would like to know where and how are you using `copiedVar` because that would help us understand what and where the problem is.